# Activate open chrome window with profile X

Tags: applescript

I wonder if there is any possibility to iterate over all open Chrome windows and check against the profile (name).

If the window has a specific name, then activate it.

I know that you can check against the URL, but I'm interested in the profile.

Thanks,

If it is possible by zsh or any other ways, that could also be interested.